# Android library project cleaning and rebuilding has problems

Tags: java, android, eclipse

`Environment:`

```
IDE: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 3.7.1
Plugin: ADT 14.0.0.v2011101719
Host: Fedora 13 
JDK: 1.6.0_21
```

Eclipse seems to have problems cleaning and rebuilding projects, when at least one project is an Android Library project, and another is an Android project dependent on the library project.

I building this Application [CSipSimple](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/wiki/HowToBuild).I getting Some four errors saying as follows :

```
The container 'Library Projects' references non existing library
'/bin/com_actionbarsherlock.jar'

The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved

The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. 
Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build
path then try building this project

The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly 
referenced from required .class files
```

Can anyone known this issue ? if it can be solve any way ?

Comment: have you checked your JDK version ?

Comment: ya checked nothing problem with the JDK version

Comment: ok, does your project contains Android library in Project's library path ?

Comment: go to Project Menu, select Properties, Now from the dialogbox select Java Library, in right side tab in Library section you will found it.

Comment: Nope , thr is no library files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok , try these steps,

Go to Project Menu, select Properties. 
A dialog Box will be appear, In that dialog box, from left side, choose the Android Option , now in the right side choose the Android version you are developing for.

Now again Clean & Build the Project.

Comment: Ya i can do that but problems remain same and i can see that when i set target for android , for the next time target has not set when i open it again

Comment: is it like you have opened an Android Project downloaded from web ?

Comment: means ? I am not getting you.

Comment: No i cant send those files because size is max, i have two source project .One is android library and other one is android source project depending on library n in android library project i getting these errors . I downloaded from http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/wiki/HowToBuild

Comment: try this, there will a file called, .classpath ( hidden ) in your project folder, it will be in read only mode, so just remove that read only mode & try above steps again.

Comment: ya i removed it changed permission but problem remain same

Comment: did you clean project again ?

Comment: I havent receive yet, however i will check it after lunch. see ya

Comment: for live conversation , you can come to my chat room , http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6137/